# Regular expression - amount with comma and decimal

Tags: regex

```
^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

From above regular expression:

- 0.1 ---> not valid
- 0.10 ---> valid
- 10  ---> valid
- 100.00 ---> valid
- -0.1 ---> not valid
- -0.10 ---> not valid
- -10 ---> not valid
- -100.00 ---> not valid

Now I want to add the comma into my regular expression as below:

- 1,000.00 ---> valid
- 10,000.00 ---> valid
- 100,000.00 ---> valid
- 1,000,000.00 ---> valid
- -1,000.00 ---> not valid

How should I correct my regular expression?

Comment: Is `-1,000.00` invalid because of the presence of the comma, or the presence of the `-`?

Comment: - , not allow negative amount.

Comment: `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|0)(\.[0-9]{2})?$`

Comment: @Wolf: Negative numbers are already invalid in the original expression and test cases.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Post it as an answer please.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to improve your answer: especially the grouping by `,` seems unclear. Thanks :-)

Comment: would `1000` and `10000` be vaild?

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish Yes, they are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regular expression you need to change

```
[1-9][0-9]*
```

which stand for "one or more digits starting from non-zero", to

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*
```

which stands for "one to three digits starting from non-zero `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`, followed by any numbers of groups with three digits each `(,[0-9]{3})*`".

The resulting regular expression will be:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|0)(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

Comment: Thanks for finally posting this as an answer :-) If you wish to explain the parts (I'm guessing this from the *italics*), did you try break it into sections? I just tried it (in preview) with quotes, and it looked easier to get.

Comment: @Wolf Not sure that I understand what you mean, I am not very good in English. I tried to improve my post. If you think, you can make it better, feel free to edit.